# How to output a word based on the probability of it occurring in a text?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Say I have 3 words and a frequency of them occurring in a piece of text.

For example:

be (1)

not (1)

have (2)

Since the total frequency of all the words is 4, I generate a random number between 0-3 or 1-4. How would I use this random number so that the program outputs "be" 1/4 of the time, "not" 1/4 of the time, and "have" 1/2 of the time?

Comment: Helpful reading: [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::string> table;
```

start with that.

```
unsigned int total(){
  if(table.empty())
    return 0;
  return table.back().first;
}
void add_word(std::string word, unsigned int count){
  unsigned current = total();
  table[current+count]=word;
}
```

now `table` contains a map from the cumulative weight of a string and all "before" it to string.

```
std::string pick( unsigned int x ){
  return table.lower_bound(x).second;
}
```

pick a random number from `1` to `total()` inclusive.  Call `pick(x)` to get the weighted probability string.

Comment: What is all this unsigned stuff? Is this unsigned int?

Comment: @tawh yes `unsigned` is another name for `unsigned int`.  Edited `int` in as it appears to have confused you.